# Get ID on click of a button AJAX way

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am building a small application using ASP.NET MVC Core 3.1.

I am displaying few buttons on the View. Each row has a button. When a button is clicked corresponding to a row, I want to get the ID value of this row but without page refresh. It should be done using AJAX.

The View code is something like this:

```
@using Updater.Models

@model IEnumerable<TemplateData> 
@{
    Layout = null;
}
 
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">

    @if (Model.Count() > 0)
    {
        <hr />
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="height:600px">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>Observation Type</th>
                <th>EmpName</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (TemplateData sheet in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@sheet.ID</td>
                    <td>@sheet.Location</td>
                    <td>@sheet.ObservationType</td>
                    <td>@sheet.EmpName</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownList("CI Status", new List<SelectListItem>
                      {
                         new SelectListItem{ Text="", Value = "0" },
                         new SelectListItem{ Text="Completed", Value = "1" },
                         new SelectListItem{ Text="In-Progress", Value = "2" },
                         new SelectListItem{ Text="Review", Value = "3" },
                      })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "sheet", FormMethod.Post))
                        {
                            <input type="submit" value="Update Status" class="ids" data-id="@sheet.ID" />
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    }
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.ids').click(function() {
        var rowID = $(this).data('id');
        alert(rowID);
});
</script>
```

** Edited **

In continuation of what Costa suggested below to call controller from Javascript, I attempted below code, but instead of showing message, it is directing to URL: http://localhost/sheet

```
               <tr>
                    <td>
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "sheet", FormMethod.Post))
                        {
                            <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Update Status" class="ids" data-id="@sheet.ID" onClick="UpdateStatus(@sheet.ID)"/>
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    }
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("Home", "UpdateStatus")',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: id,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function() { alert('Success'); },
    error: function() { alert('Error'); }
});
</script>
```

Controller Code

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("UpdateStatus")]
        public void UpdateStatus()
        {
            //Do Something
        }
}
```

Comment: Change `type="submit"` to `type="button"` and change `$('.ids').click(function(){ ... }` to `$(document).on("click",".ids",function(){ ... })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass the ID to javascript, you can use this:

```
      <input type="submit" value="Update Status" class="ids" data-id="@sheet.ID" onClick="UpdateStatus(@sheet.ID)" />
        
      <script>
      function UpdateStatus(string id) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/UpdateStatus",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {"id": id},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function() { alert('Success'); },
        error: function() { alert('Error'); }
       });
       }
      </script>
```

Finally, edit your controller like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("UpdateStatus/{id}")]
    public void UpdateStatus(string id)
    {
        //Do Something
    }
```

Comment: I want to call a controller method from within JS function.

Comment: I edited the answer on how to pass the id with ajax, and I suppose your controller function signature inside the parentheses is only: string id

Comment: Updating original post with modified code.

Comment: Modified original post

Comment: Please post your c# controller as well. And do you have a UpdateStatus function in your js? You need that in order to pass the id to js.

Comment: Edited answer again, make sure to change both js + c# . It should work now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234070/discussion-between-costa-and-rkh).